# Convert decimal number to fixed point binary on Excel

Tags: excel, math, binary, fixed-point

I have a column with decimal values (in this case, sine values, but it's irrelevant), for example: 0,024541229, and I need to convert it to a signed fixed point binary number, with 2 bits for the whole part (the -2 to +1 range is enougth, as sine values range from -1 to +1), and 6 bits for the fractional part.

Of course there will be loss of precision, as 1/(2^6) = 0,015625.

The Excel functions DEC2BIN() or BASE() doens't seem to be useful for that.

Comment: Maybe you want DEC2BIN instead?

Comment: Nice catch. Fixed. Thanks @findwindow

Comment: Not sure if 2 bits are enough for the exponent because you'd need a large negative exponent for value near to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fixed-point number is essentially an integer scaled by a fixed amount. In this case, if your real number is stored in *A1*, then the conversion to fixed-point would be:

```
=INT(A1*2^6)
```

This will scale the number to 1.570638656 and truncate it to 1.

Comment: It worked perfectly for all positive values, but not for the negatives: 0.024541229 converted to 1, 0.0000000 to 0, but -0,024541229 is being converted to -2, I think it should be -1. Am I wrong on this assumption?

Comment: @AndréBaptista `INT()` rounds down towards negative infinity. That's just one way to round from a fractional number to an integer. Other options can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-a-number-f82b440b-689d-4221-b21e-38da99d33435?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).